# Twitter - Max Statuses Per Hour

Tags: api, twitter

The Twitter API states that there is a limit of 150 request/hour, but also states that there is a limit of 3200 requests/page.  Am I to understand that the number of statuses/hour is limited to 150*3200?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand. Requesting for status does not count in that 150 limit. If you trying to update your status or send DM then they are counted in the API limit.

So if you are requesting for your past tweets then you will be able to get upto 3200 tweets.